# Gnome Remote Desktop: Can't find option to log out PC while remote user is logged in

Tags: fedora, gnome, remote-desktop

I wanted to set up the remote desktop connection for a Fedora 36 PC at my uni and I simply went to the settings->sharing and turned on remote desktop for both controlling and viewing.

We like to configure our Windows PCs so that when a remote user logs in remotely, the PC logs out. If someone logs in from the physical PC, the remote user is kicked out and you can control the PC from the physical location again.

Somehow I have configured the Fedora PC in such a way that it doesn't log out when someone logs in remotely and both can control the PC at the same time. I've had fights over the cursor with other members from my working group, big fun.

Naturally, this is not an ideal solution and I would like to know how I can configure gnome-remote-desktop so that this doesn't happen. I have tried searching in the sharing settings, but I do not see any advanced options or anything. Googling the issue also didn't yield any helpful results.

I tried to ChatGPT the whole issue and it told me to install a program called "vino", just to discover that dnf doesn't know what that is.

What can I do to change the settings in gnome remote desktop so that two users cannot be logged in at the same time and fight over the cursor?

PS: I also discovered that remote logging in only works if the PC is already logged in. So I set the PC to never log out and it's just standing there with it's screen turned on the entire time. Is there an easy fix for this?